# Query with multiple field values specified

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform an elasticsearch query with multiple fields specified. Here is some pseudo code which hopefully illustrates my intention:

```
"query" : {
  "query_string" : { "query" : "william" }
},
"filter" : {
  "missing" : { "field" : "membership_expires_on" }
},
"filter" : {
  "missing" : { "field" : "gender" }
},
"filter" : {
  "terms" : { "status" : "p"}
},
"filter" : {
  "terms" : { "unit_id" : "4"}
}
```

I'm trying to AND all these filters together, but from the [elasticsearch doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter.html) I can't figure out how to put these specific filters into a single query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: Here is what I have so far:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "membership_expires_on"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "p"
              }
            },
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "gender"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "unit": "4"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "william"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

But this returns no results, so I'm doing something wrong. Am I wielding the bool filter with the array inside in an illegal manner?

**Update 2**: I've confirmed that the JSON above indeed is a valid query, so there's probably something amiss with my data/index. That will be a question for another day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [BoolFilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html). It should help.

Comment: Can you add also in your question one of your docs and your mapping if you have defined one?

Comment: Will elasticsearch accept an array inside a must clause? Or can it only be inside a should clause?

Comment: As far as I understand your comment, yes you can add multiple queries in a must clause.